# Fwrite seems to always append instead of writing from cursor

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I am writing and reading structs to and from a binary file on linux (xubuntu 13.10). First: I open it:

```
dtbFile = fopen(dtbLocation,"ab+");
```

Next up: I am going to write the following struct to it a couple of times (9)

```
typedef struct{
char flagRemoved; //This flag indicates if the struct is still used. If its not 0 (as in 00000000 or \0), the thing is removed
int value;
time_t timeStamp;
}__attribute__( ( packed ) ) DTBItem_HDD; //Prevent padding to save RAM and HDD
```

Then printing everything to prove that this went okay:

> flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 1 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime):
>   Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 2 Item Timestamp
>   (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0
>   Item value: 3 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21
>   11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 4 Item Timestamp (expressed
>   as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 5
>   Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013
>   flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 6 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime):
>   Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 7 Item Timestamp
>   (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0
>   Item value: 8 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21
>   11:46:23 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 9 Item Timestamp (expressed
>   as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:46:23 2013

The function that prints:

```
int printHDDContent(void){
//First: we are always at EOF so rewind.
rewind(dtbFile);
DTBItem_HDD hddItem;
DTBItem item; //Used to print the contents of the DTBItem_HDD
int iAmountRead; //Used to find eof
while (1){ //Cant put anything usefull here, since EOF is detected elswhere
    iAmountRead = fread(&hddItem,sizeof(hddItem),1,dtbFile);
    if (iAmountRead != 1){
        if (!feof(dtbFile)){ //Check if EOF, and if not its error time!
            return 11;
        }
        break; //EOF, break out of the while loop
    }
    //Convert it to a DTBItem and print it, but only if flagRemoved is still 0
    printf("flagRemoved = %d\n",hddItem.flagRemoved);
    if (!hddItem.flagRemoved){ //Check the flagRemoved
        item.value = hddItem.value;
        item.timeStamp = hddItem.timeStamp;
        printDTBItem(&item);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

So, this is where I get to my question. The next thing I want to do is remove items from the file by marking them as removed, by setting the flagRemoved property to something that is not 0. For this I wrote the following piece of code:

```
if (shouldBeRemoved){
            int itemSeek = -1 * (int)sizeof(hddItem);
            printf("Removing..(%d, %zu)\n",hddItem.value, hddItem.timeStamp);
            iErr = fseek(dtbFile,itemSeek,SEEK_CUR); 
            if (iErr) return 11; //Error while seeking (unknown file error)
            hddItem.flagRemoved = 1; //Set the removedFlag
            iErr = fwrite(&hddItem,sizeof(DTBItem_HDD),1,dtbFile); //Write the item back to the file
            if (iErr != 1) return 11; //Should be one, bacuse one item is written. If not: unknown error with file
        }
```

And here is where it goes wrong: Whenever I use fwrite here it always seeks to the end of the file and then writes this new object instead of from the start of the cursor, where it would overwrite its old counterpart. Why is this happening? Accorind to what I read here: [on CPP Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) it should write to the currentposition in stream, but this is the print after trying to remove all the items:

> flagRemoved = 0
>   Item value: 1 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21
>   11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 2 Item Timestamp (expressed
>   as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 3
>   Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013
>   flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 4 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime):
>   Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 5 Item Timestamp
>   (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 0
>   Item value: 6 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21
>   11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 7 Item Timestamp (expressed
>   as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 8
>   Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime): Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013
>   flagRemoved = 0 Item value: 9 Item Timestamp (expressed as localtime):
>   Mon Oct 21 11:56:08 2013 flagRemoved = 1

The additional 1 at the end indicates one more item, which has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the whole mistake was opening it in read/write/append mode: this mode always appends its writes, no matter what. Because I cannot guarantee the file exists, I changed the file open code to the following:

```
int initDatabase(char* dtbLocation){
int iErrCode = 0;
if (dtbFile == NULL){
    dtbFile = fopen(dtbLocation,"ab+"); //Open the file in read/write-append binary mode (do not overwrite current content, create if not exists) at the end of the file
    if (dtbFile == NULL){
        iErrCode = 2; //The file could not be opened
    } else if (fclose(dtbFile) == EOF){ //Close the file to re-open it in the correct way 
        iErrCode = 12;  //Something went wrong while closing file
    } else {
        dtbFile = fopen(dtbLocation,"rb+"); //Open in read/write, file must exist
        if (dtbFile == NULL){
            iErrCode = 2; //The file could not be opened
        }   
    }   
}
} else {
    iErrCode = 1; //The file was already opened
}
return iErrCode;
```

}

Comment: Your analysis is correct. Your solution looks a bit complicated, but it does seem to be the only way to create the file, but not truncate it if it exists. Unfortunately the `fopen` interface is messed up (the POSIX `open` interface has separate flag for create-if-not-exists and truncate-if-exists, so you can give all combinations, but the standard C interface does not).